# Why is this rails 6 view not activating the form-inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, simple-form

I have a simple-form Rails 6 application that does not activate a view html when using the link_to buttons in the application view.  Here is the application view, I have tried moving the link_to commands into the body and that did not change the failure.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mypantry</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%=link_to 'Settings', setting_path %> | <%= link_to 'Groceries', mupcs_path %> | <%= link_to 'Stores', stores_path %> | <%= link_to 'Open Pickup List', shops_path %> | <%= link_to 'Shoping List', list_path %>
      
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the view form that is being called by the 'setup' button:

```
        <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <%= simple_form_for :search, url: setting_path, method: "GET", html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :id, collection: @stores, label: false, prompt: "Store Options: Blank Store" %></td>
        <td>
        <%= f.collection_select :buyer, @buyers, :buyer, :buyer, prompt: "Blank Buyer" %>
        </td><td>
         <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    </td>
    </tr></table>



<b>the buyer:&nbsp;</b>
<%= cookies.encrypted.permanent[:thebuyer] %>
<p>
<b>the store:&nbsp;</b> 
<% a = cookies.encrypted.permanent[:thestore_id] %>
<% if a.to_i > 0 %>
    <%= @stores[a.to_i - 1]["name"] %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when safari changes from one link_to item to "setup", the submit button does not work until the form is manually refreshed.  Why must I manually refresh?

Comment: I should have said settings, not setup.  It's late.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on an alternate link using html that works.
Basically, change:
<%= link_to 'xxx', xxx_path %>
to:
xxx

Using target="self" forces the action to stays in the same browser window/tab but fully activates? the form-inline function so that the submit button works from the get-go.